# ajax code not updating in MySQL database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Have an ajax code which displays errors and success on the page but doesn't actually update the database when I click submit button.

The form has a select dropdown and the options are populated from the database. I know the PHP code works because without the ajax, the table gets updated so I must be missing something in the ajax but can't find?

form.php with the script

```
<form id="test" name="test" method="POST" action="test.php">
            <select id="updateid" name="updateid">
                <option value="">- Please Select -</option>
                <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT updateid, name FROM test";
                    $res = $con->query($sql);
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                    echo "<option value=".$row['updateid'].">".$row['name']."</option>";
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submitbut" />
</form>



 $(document).ready(function(){
$('#submitbut').click(function(e){

        var updateid = $("#updateid").val();

            if(updateid.length == 0){
            $("#success").text("make a selection.");
            $("updateid").focus();
        }
    else{

        var dataString = 'updateid='+ updateid

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'test.php',
            data: {updateid:dataString}
        }).done(function(){
            $('#success').text('success!');
        });
    }
        e.preventDefault();
        });    
});
```

test.php

```
<?php       
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $updateid= $_POST['updateid'];

        $sql = "UPDATE `test` SET `test`='abcdegfhi' WHERE `updateid` = '$updateid'";

        if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {

            echo "ok";
        } else {
            echo "nope";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    var dataString = 'updateid='+ updateid
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^

        data: {updateid:dataString}
               ^^^^^^^^^
```

Your PHP script will be receiving:

```
 updateid=updateid=42
    ^--- $_POST key
          ^^^^^^^^^^^ $_POST value
```

which you then blindly insert into your query (enjoy your server getting totally pwn3d via your [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability):

```
$sql = "[..snip..]WHERE `updateid` = 'updateid=42'"
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: The question isn't about SQL injection though, is it? Thanks but not answering my question. But, on the topic, while you're here. How would I improve that then? Would the query be `$stmt = $db->prepare('update test set test = ? where updateid = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('abcdefghi',$test,$updateid);
$stmt->execute();`

Comment: Exactly HOW is this not answering your question? I've pointed out exactly why it's failing - you're passing bad data into your `where` clause, causing the query to match nothing.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['submit'] is not set.
All $_POST data comes from ajax request - not html post request ( You have used the "e.preventDefault()" ).

You can set data as follows:

{updateid:dataString, submit: true}

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work, still not updating when submit is clicked.